# Easiest-to-use Python package that automates GUI interactions and supports image recognition/detection

Tags: windows, python, automation, image-recognition

There's a lot of solid GUI automation python packages but I have a specific set of requirements needed for a recommendation to one of our more advanced QAs.

I'd like to know in 2019 what is the easiest to pick up and run with python GUI automation package that supports image-recognition instead as well as coordinates being hard-coded for finding and interacting with GUI elements.

There's no requirement to scan/assess under-the-hood GUI ids or handles.

The end-goal is to integrate it with Appium for automated user-workflow-style testing.

Currently it's only needed for Windows but I suspect that will change later. I will however accept Windows-only answers.

Update: One more thing to mention: support has to be good for it, whether that's an active Q&A community or in-depth how-tos. That makes SIKULI a no-go from my own personal past experiences with the product. None of my attempts to get feedback for highly specific questions from them produced *any* feedback, so I can't in good consciousness recommend it even if it is ostensibly a very easy to start using GUI scripting tool that supports image recognition.

Comment: Was your poor experience with SIKULI or SIKULI-X?

Comment: I've only worked with SIKULI-X, but to be clear I didn't have a poor experience with SIKULI-X itself so much as I hit a wall, got no feedback from multiple points of contact, and taking that into consideration cannot recommend our QAs with some coding/scripting skills to use it. Personally I loved how easy it was to use for most GUI automation, but it just wasn't enough due to lack of sufficient examples/support/explicit enough documentation. If the community can't support them and neither can I, they'd be left high and dry.

Comment: Maybe support could come __initially__ from yourself & your _potential_ users by starting an online wiki/usergroup of your own as the kernel of something that could grow with time.

Comment: I had stated that A) I was never unblocked due to lack of support (ergo no support from my end) and B) this isn't even for me personally using it, just to recommended it for our QAs with some coding/scripting skills that want to get the ball rolling on some GUI automation with user-style testing. Why would I want to become the support in this context...?